# CDN Datatables switch language

Tags: jquery, internationalization, datatables

I am using datatables from [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) within a **multi-language application**. I know how to switch the language of the table with simply passing the language file or customizing the strings by myself.

```
 "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/lang.json"
        }
```

But is there a possibility to change the language according to the users **browser settings**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunetaly, the [langauge packages](https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/i18n/) are named by language names, not by  language codes :

> //cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/i18n/Finnish.json
>   //cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/i18n/French.json

etc. So you must built a map that translates language codes to language names :

```
var langMap = {
   'en' : 'English',
   'da' : 'Danish',
   'se' : 'Swedish'
   //etc, the languages you want to support
}
```

Now you can pass the correct language package URL to dataTables that corresponds to the current browser language :

```
function getLanguage() {
    var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
    return '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/i18n/'+langMap[lang]+'.json'
}

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    language : {
        url: getLanguage()
    }
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3er6f4w6/**

Comment: Thank you. So obvious now you said it, why didn't I get it.. I was only searching for some built-in feature.